# Forcing urlparse.urlsplit to preserve str case

Tags: python, urlparse

Is there any way to force urlparse's urlsplit function to preserve the case of the str passed in? It preserves the case of the path in the returned tuple, but not of the netloc, and this is important to me. (I know domain names are case-insensitive, but, we're doing some A/B testing with different capitalizations of the name, and need to preserve case.)

Thanks.

Comment: That's strange -- at least for me (Python 2.6), `urlparse.urlsplit('http://Www.ExamPle.com/').netloc` gives `'Www.ExamPle.com'` with case preserved.

Comment: Maybe it is implementation/platform specific, since I see camel-case `Www.ExamPle.com` in my python. I have some crazy idea which maybe useful: parse the url, get netloc, make a case-insensitive regular expression (you need to screen `.`s) and search in the source URL.

Comment: The netloc isn't being `lower()`ed on Python 2.7.x either: http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/urlparse.py?view=markup   What version of Python are you on?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to force urlsplit to do that.

You can, however, wrap it and then do some dirty work to restore case, or copy the source code and do the modification yourself. Or write the function from scratch, of course.

I'd go for the second option.